# Error assigning string value to integer variable

Tags: c#

initialize variable and assign int value to it and at run time assigning a string value it give error.

```
var _formatedBillCode = 101; 

_formatedBillCode="20160919_101_ank"; // assigning string value
```

Comment: `var` is resolved at compile time, not run time. You can't possibly change its initial type inference.

Comment: In c# "var" is different from javascript. It's not dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` would infer its type in compile time. Unlike JS, `var` here inferred its type in compile time when you defined it with an integer first.

Later if you move with changing its type, it would throw an error because at compile time, the first type it inferred was `int`. You can't change it to `string`.

Use `dynamic` types for your purpose in this case like the following if you need dynamic that much:

```
dynamic a = 1;
Console.WriteLine(a);

// Dynamic now has a different type.
a = new string[0];
Console.WriteLine(a);

// Assign to dynamic method result.
a = Test();
Console.WriteLine(a);

// Use dynamic field.
_y = "carrot";

// You can call anything on a dynamic variable,
// ... but it may result in a runtime error.
Console.WriteLine(_y.Error);
```

And in your case here;

```
dynamic_formatedBillCode = 101; 

_formatedBillCode="20160919_101_ank"; // assigning string value
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. This link will also helpful  [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b1df45/var-vs-dynamic-keywords-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jennifer/2010/06/16/what-is-the-difference-between-var-and-dynamic-in-c/) to be more concise and to the point. :)

Answer (score 1):

use [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd264736.aspx) to push datatype resolving to runtime.

```
    dynamic _formatedBillCode = 101; 

    _formatedBillCode="20160919_101_ank";
```

Answer (score 0):

As first you declaring "_formatedBillCode" as int, you cant change the type to string after that, "var" isn't dynamic, it just represent the type.
you can use "dynamic" instead of "var".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a string value to an int, that wont work without casting it. This will assign the second variable as a string with the integer cast to string:

```
var _formatedBillCodeInt = 101; 

var _formatedBillCode="20160919_" + _formatedBillCodeInt.ToString() + "_ank"; // assigning string value
```

Or did I misunderstand the question?